# Conditional piecewise function with dynamic boundries

Tags: pyomo, piecewise

This equation is part of a large model. K1 and K2 are constants, x1 and x2 are model variables:

[image: The equation I am trying to implement]

All other piecewise functions seen previously have fixed boundaries and I have no idea how to compute boundaries during runtime.